# CMake : Selecting mpich over openmpi

Tags: cmake, mpi, mpich

I am using cmake 3.10.2. I have both openmpi  and mpich installed. However I need to load only mpich. So I found from the documentation the following

> [MPI_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/module/FindMPI.html)
>
> A suffix which is appended to all names that are being looked for.
>   For instance you may set this to .mpich or .openmpi to prefer the one
>   or the other on Debian and its derivatives.

My CMake file goes like this

```
set(MPI_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX ".mpich")
FIND_PACKAGE(MPI REQUIRED)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${MPI_INCLUDE_DIRS})
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${MPI_LIBRARY_DIRS})
message(${MPI_INCLUDE_PATH})
```

However this shows

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/include/openmpi/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/include...
```

Where am I going wrong. Could you please help me with this

Also

```
mpicc -show
gcc -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/include/openmpi -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/include/openmpi/opal/mca/event/libevent2022/libevent -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/include/openmpi/opal/mca/event/libevent2022/libevent/include -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/include -pthread -L/usr//lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib -lmpi

mpicc.mpich -show
gcc -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -I/usr/include/mpich -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmpich
```

Comment: Update your PATH so `which mpicc` shows mpich is used. And the run again cmake and make. If I understand correctly, suffix is for the binaries built by make, and not for choosing a given MPI library.

Comment: Oh... I tried setting mpich by using update-alternatives. That works fine... However other progs need openmpi as default... Is there any other way to point to mpich directory by giving a kind of flag perhaps

Comment: `update-alternatives` is local to your system. If you manually update `$PATH`, it will be local to your session (e.g. terminal) and will not affect other programs ran from other terminals. An other option is point `cmake` to the full mpich mpicc : `cmake -DMPI_CC_COMPILER=/.../mpicc`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet The second option works great. Thanks

Comment: note you cannot use MPICH `mpirun` with your Open MPI app, so at some point in time, you will have to update your `$PATH` or use the full path to Open MPI `mpirun`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default mpicc is not your choice.  You can specify it manually in the cmake file, or update the $PATH variable with your mpicc included before the default one. Personally, I installed the mpich in the /usr/local/ directory. 
Regards

Answer (score 3):

the best is to use modules for switch between openmpi and mpich:

```
$ module load mpich
$ module unload mpich  
$ module load openmpi
```

http://modules.sourceforge.net/